# Why can't I join any Minecraft Multiplayer servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

This just started happening today:

I have minecraft installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For some reason multiplayer doesn't work for me: I get a good ping for the server but every time I attempt to join, for the first few moments everything works and chat is working but then, all the players freeze, chat doesn't work, portals don't work, and when I type something in chat, it doesn't show up. After 5 more seconds, I get kicked from the server and it says "Connection lost Timed Out".

I've tried joining many servers (hypixel, mineplex, etc.) but none of them work (the same thing happens to all of them). I've tried restarting my computer 2 times, disconnecting and reconnecting my wifi, and I re-installed minecraft.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a java/network issue, not a Minecraft issue - I've never had this problem ever. What version of Java are you using & how are you launching Minecraft?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I launch Minecraft from Unity Dash and I use 1.6.13 for the launcher, and, uh, how do you tell what version of Java you are using?

Comment: Run `java --version` in Terminal. I assume you used the Minecraft Peeps PPA?

Comment: Yes, I did use the Minecraft Peeps PPA. By the way, I think it's only "-version" not "--version". It says my java version is "1.7.0_79", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), and OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode).

Comment: Ah. I would agree with Bryce's answer. Have you tried Minecraft on another computer/network and seeing if it works? Might be your machine.

Answer (score 2):

"After 5 more seconds, I get kicked from the server and it says 'Connection lost Timed Out'."

That's the problem, it sounds like your ping is dying when you join the server, try joining a much smaller server (like 5 players on it), make sure your ping is under 100 (150-ish is fine) and see if you  can play.

Other things that could cause this

- Your connection to your router - Try playing on an LAN world hosted on a family member's or friend's computer, if this does not work, you may need to contact you internet provider or router vendor for a replacement router.
- Connection to the Mojang servers (used for authentication with online-mode servers, this usually gives a different error if it is offline though)
- Connection to the game server (ping)
- Connection from your router to the server, your router might not like you playing on server or might block the ports the game uses to connect
- Your minecraft might not be "set up" correctly, like the jvm arguments, try reinstalling minecraft (highly unlikely, but still possible, make sure to back up your saves/configs/anything else you want to keep)
- That evil thing called a Firewall, try whitelisting Minecraft in it

Comment: Depending on your internet provider its also possible that - even though you have decent internet speeds - the devices your provider gives you are faulty and will not give you a stable connection. For example, after having spent many years with Comcast, I was very pleased with our service until a year or two ago when they started handing out a new model of modem/router. 5 replacements and 6 months later and the wireless feature still kicks everyone from the network every 5 minutes. I could barely play Minecraft during that time.

Comment: @LionBryce I tried joining a server with 6 people on it - same thing happened. However, I think it was lag because everything froze when I joined the tiny server, but then, for a second, it worked and I say people saying "Welcome!" and other such, but then I got kicked and it says "Connection lost Timed Out".

Comment: "that evil thing called a firewall"...please tell me that's half joke... :)

Comment: Wow, I tried joining a really small server which had no one on but was running, and the SAME THING HAPPENED. I got a good ping of the server, and it said "0/12". When I joined, the exact same thing happened and then I was kicked momentarily, with the error message saing Connection Lost Timed out.

Answer (score -3):

If you've timed out, it might be because your memory allocated for Minecraft has filled up.

As says Gnampf at [Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/tutorials-and-faqs/1871637-tutorial-allocate-more-memory-for-minecraft),

> Minecraft Launcher: Since Minecraft version 1.6.X you can use the new launcher. With this, it is possible to integrate Java commands directly into the game. Here is what you have to do:
>   Download and execute the new launcher
>   In the section "Profile Selection" click on "Edit Profile"
>   Under "Java Settings (Advanced), activate "JVM Arguments" and add into the text area this argument:
>   -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M
>   Save this profile and execute Minecraft. You will always start with 2GB of RAM.

2048M can be replaced with 2G, to make things simpler. You can also change the number to be bigger or smaller as needed.

[image: A picture, in case you can't find it.]

Comment: I got a down vote and don't understand why. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: When you run out of allocated memory the game simply crashes (or rather, the Java Virtual Machine running your game crashes) with an OutOfMemoryError. In the OP's question, the OP is asking about a TimeoutException which signifies that something in the NETWORK caused the client/server to become disconnected for 20 seconds (the default in Minecraft) or more; and since the answer to the OP's question lies in the network's instability, not lack of memory, your answer was downvoted.

Comment: @caucow Alright, sorry. I think I got the same error and fixed it that way, though.

Comment: @BassetHound Thats physically impossible.